# import class in beautifulsoup

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to import this as table from table id "octable"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=BANKNIFTY')
doc = lh.fromstring(r.content)
data = doc.xpath('//*[@id="octable"]')
type(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

however this is what i get

```
0  [[[], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []...   

                                                  1   \
0  [[], [[<Element img at 0x29d1aa5cbd8>]], [], [...   

                                                  2   \
0  [[], [[<Element img at 0x29d1aa5ca98>]], [], [...   

                                                  3   \
0  [[], [[<Element img at 0x29d1aa5cbd8>]], [], [...
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me. I'd recommend familiarizing yourself with [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=BANKNIFTY')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,features='html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'octable'})
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
[    CALLS                                               ...     PUTS
    Chart       OI Chng in OI   Volume     IV      LTP  ...      LTP     IV   Volume Chng in OI       OI  Chart
0     NaN      580         20        3      -  5929.35  ...     2.15  60.85     1300      -2920    14980    NaN
1     NaN        -          -        -      -        -  ...        -      -        -          -        -    NaN
2     NaN        -          -        -      -        -  ...     3.20  61.28       68        320      500    NaN
3     NaN     8620        -40        6      -  5585.00  ...     2.60  58.90      305        -60    13400    NaN
4     NaN        -          -        -      -        -  ...     2.50  57.62        8        -60        -    NaN
..    ...      ...        ...      ...    ...      ...  ...      ...    ...      ...        ...      ...    ...
89    NaN        -          -        -      -        -  ...        -      -        -          -        -    NaN
90    NaN       20         20        2  31.08     4.30  ...        -      -        -          -        -    NaN
91    NaN        -          -        -      -        -  ...        -      -        -          -        -    NaN
92    NaN       80         60        9  28.39     1.20  ...  3000.00      -        -          -      140    NaN
93  Total  4568440        NaN  2456057    NaN      NaN  ...      NaN    NaN  2562288        NaN  4181760  Total

[94 rows x 23 columns]]
```